# Service returned by GetGattServicesForUuidAsync doesn't help enumerate characteristics

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal, c++-winrt

Instead of searching for the service of interest, I tried the following

```
auto f = leDev.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(servUuid).get(); // returns a GattDeviceServicesResult
auto g = f.Services().GetAt(0); // There is only one such service on the device that I am using
auto h = g.GetCharacteristicsAsync().get(); // Use the service to obtain all the characteristics of the service
auto j = h.Characteristics(); // Size of j is 0 despite there are 4 services
```

The way I constructed `servUuid` is to use the string that had the service UUID

```
guid servGUIDstruct = make_guid(servID);
winrt::guid servUuid = reinterpret_cast<winrt::guid&>(servGUIDstruct);
```

I also tried other ways to obtain a service Uuid, for e.g., enumerating all services and storing the Uuid of the service of interest and then using it in `GetGattServicesForUuidAsync` but to see the same issue.

It would be very useful to know what is that I am not doing right, Thanks

Comment: I find that the call to `GetCharacteristicsAsync` returned with a status `Access denied`

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I understand is that since I have already enumerated all the services and characteristics therein, I have to call `Close` on the services before obtaining a service again.
Here's [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattdeviceservice.close?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_GenericAttributeProfile_GattDeviceService_Close) that explains possibly why the access has been denied.